# HighCharts multi-level pie

Tags: highcharts, pie-chart

Is it possible to make a pie chart like in the image below using highcharts (highcharts.com)?

The 2nd level is filled partially.

[image: Multi-Level Pie Chart]

Example in jsfiddle would be great.

Thanks for advice.

Comment: In general it's not supported - pie need to be fully drawn. However, you cant create this empty spaces just by setting opacity=100% for slice color.

Comment: yeah, seems there is no other way ...
thanks for answer